# between two vows of burning adoration

Tags: meaning

This is the story about Elizabeth I and Philip II from "rewards and Fairies" Gloriana by Kipling.

> 'What's here? Philip complains that certain of her gentlemen have fought 
>   against his generals in the Low Countries.
>   He prays her to hang 'em when they re-enter her realms. (Hm, that's as
>   may be.) Here's a list of burnt shipping slipped between two vows of
>   burning adoration. Oh, poor Philip! His admirals at sea--no less than
>   three of 'em--have been boarded, sacked, and scuttled on their lawful
>   voyages by certain English mariners (gentlemen, he will not call them),
>   who are now at large and working more piracies in his American ocean,
>   which the Pope gave him.

I can not understand the meaning below.

> Here's a list of burnt shipping slipped between two vows of
>   burning adoration.

What is "two vows of burning adoration"?

Comment: Please use quote markers so we know what parts of your question are the excerpts.

Comment: The list comes between two passages of the letter in which Philip vows (swears) that he loves Elizabeth with burning (fiery, hot, fervent) adoration (worship).